# ¿Cómo hacer if/else con .css?

Tags: jquery, css

```js
if ($('p') == $('p').css('color', 'limegreen')) {
                alert("Si");
            } else {
                alert("No");
            }
```

```css
p {
            color: limegreen;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Title </title>
    <style>
        p {
            color: limegreen;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hola mundo</p>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Que es lo que estas tratando de hacer?

Comment: Lo hice lo más sencillo posible para que se entienda perfectamente, lo que quiero hacer es saber los estilos de una etiqueta o div y apartir de eso hacer una condicional y por supuesto una funcion.

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/183711/edit) tu pregunta agregando una descripción de lo que quieres lograr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serias algo asi:

```
  if ($('p').css('color') == 'limegreen') {
```

A esto añado que `$('p').css('color')` devolverá la propiedad rgb del color y no el nombre

```
limegreen = rgb(50, 205, 50)
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if ($('p').css('color') == 'limegreen') {
                alert("Si");
            } else {
                alert($('p').css('color'));
            }
};
```

```css
 p {
            color: limegreen;
        }
```

```html
 <p>Hola mundo</p>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio, ¿y en caso de hacer por ejemplo un opacitiy == 1?

Comment: Reemplazas  $('p').css('color') por $('p').css('opacity') y devolverá '1' por defecto o el valor opacity en ese momento

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.